# .NET Core endpoint not found after setting to app url

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

A member of my team set an API Endpoint as the App URL in the project properties of an ASP.NET Core 2 application. After doing so and then removing it, we can no longer access the endpoint and receive a 404 error.

This only happens when running under IIS Express. When I switch to my local IIS it works just fine. Switch back to IIS Express, 404 again. We are using Visual Studio 2017.

There are no lingering settings in the `launchSettings.json`, web config, or project file that I have found.

Any ideas what would cause this?

**EDIT:**

Initial IIS EXPRESS App URL: http://localhost:8085

If I change that to http://localhost:8085/api/values nothing works.

So, I change it back to http://localhost:8085

Now, I cannot get to http://localhost:8085/api/values in the web browser. It's like setting the endpoint as the app URL just killed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alan Silva was correct.

The below lines were in the applicationhost.config. Deleting them caused the expected behavior.

```
<application path="/Values" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Repository\TEst\WebApplication1\WebApplication1" />
    </application>
    <application path="/api/Values" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Repository\TEst\WebApplication1\WebApplication1" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS express is hosting your application in a different port than your local IIS.  I suggest you to run your application on IIS express, check the port that is being used and change the endpoint url accordingly.

Comment: I realize the difference in hosting. My problem is that when I navigate to to localhost with the correct port on IIS Express and tack on the endpoint, it no longer functions after having set the entire endpoint as the app url. See my edit above for clarification.

Comment: Can you check if deleting the .vs folder solves your problem?